# MySQL field default value not applied on join

Tags: mysql, sql

I've written a CREATE statement with -1 default value for some INT fields :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table (
    country_id INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT -1,
    ...)
```

When making a join with UPDATE, the non-matching values are replaced by 0, instead of -1 as I expected :

```
 UPDATE table AS t1 
SET 
    t1.country_id = (SELECT 
            t2.id
        FROM
            country AS t2
        WHERE
            t1.country = t2.country
            );
```

=> When the UPDATE doesnt find a match, country_id is set to 0 instead of -1

Any idea on how to get the correct behaviour ?

Comment: So you get 0 when the SELECT returns no value?!? Amazing.

Comment: your sure your table didn't had anny country_id's with value 0 before running this update query?? it doenst make anny sense MySQL is updating non matching values from that select with 0 values.

Comment: Solution found : the problem was before the join. I had an INSERT before the UPDATE importing some values larger than INT(11). In this case, the inserted value is 0 and not -1.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you write the query as:

```
UPDATE table t1 JOIN
       country t2
       ON t1.country = t2.country
    SET t1.country_id = t2.id;
```

But I do agree that your code should work, inserting the explicit default value when the subquery has no match.